# Netsuite namespace issues

Tags: python, web-services, netsuite

I'm currently working on a side project using python and NetSuite Webservices. I've been able to send off a request for data centers successfully. I'm using the element tree import to parse the xml requests and responses. No matter what I try to grab one of the urls below I end up getting no value and I'm assuming this has to do with name spacing which i'm terrible with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <platformMsgs:documentInfo xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2016_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <platformMsgs:nsId>WEBSERVICES__XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</platformMsgs:nsId>
        </platformMsgs:documentInfo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getDataCenterUrlsResponse xmlns="">
            <platformCore:getDataCenterUrlsResult xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2016_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <platformCore:status isSuccess="true" />
                <platformCore:dataCenterUrls>
                    <platformCore:restDomain>https://rest.na1.netsuite.com</platformCore:restDomain>
                    <platformCore:webservicesDomain>https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com</platformCore:webservicesDomain>
                    <platformCore:systemDomain>https://system.na1.netsuite.com</platformCore:systemDomain>
                </platformCore:dataCenterUrls>
            </platformCore:getDataCenterUrlsResult>
        </getDataCenterUrlsResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ns = {'platformCore': 'urn:messages_2016_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'}
xml.find('platformCore:webservicesDomain', ns)
```

the xml.find() never returns anything but null values regardless of selector or namespacing. If someone could relay to me what the correct way was so I could get this url and other data from these responses I'd appreciate it.

If you are wondering why I'm doing things the hard way instead of using a client or a better tool. I'm trying to embed some webservice functionality inside of sublime text 3 which uses a specific version of python 3 (3.3.6) and makes importing libraries not impossible but a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should probably try:

```
xml.find('{urn:messages_2016_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}webservicesDomain')
```

or

```
ns = {'nsp': 'urn:messages_2016_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'}
xml.find('nsp:webservicesDomain', ns)
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been super busy recently. I'll give this a go and see if it works